# ¿Cuándo se usa "aparte" y cuándo "a parte"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ortografía

Escribí [una respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15172/1674) hace poco y Gorpik me corrigió una frase:

> Bromas *a parte*, sí tiene diferencia, aunque no mucha.

Dejándola (correctamente) en:

> Bromas **aparte**, sí tiene diferencia, aunque no mucha.

Creo (espero :D) no ser el único que se confunde al respecto.
¿Podría alguien explicar cuál es la regla general?

Sería interesante crear alguna respuesta que se pueda usar de referencia para el futuro.

Nótese el interesante artículo de Fundéu, [«aparte» no es lo mismo que «a parte»](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/aparte-a-parte/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una buena respuesta a esto la encuentras en el siguiente enlace del cual voy a transcribir algunos apartes.  [Blog Lengua-e](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2008/aparte-o-a-parte/)

> Como norma general, aparte se escribe junto. La grafía en dos palabras
>   tan solo es correcta cuando podemos introducir un artículo entre a y
>   parte (y esto solo ocurre en casos excepcionales). Vamos a ver todo el
>   problema poco a poco.
>
> Aparte (en una sola palabra) tiene diferentes usos. En uno de ellos es
>   un adverbio que significa ‘**en otro lugar**’, ‘**separado**’ o
>   incluso ‘**a un lado, al margen**’, como en el ejemplo (1):
>
> (1) He tratado de dejar aparte todos los prejuicios que he ido
>   acumulando contra el libro, leerlo, y luego formarme una opinión
>   concreta [Tatuado en papel, acceso: 19-4-2008].
>
> También existe la locución aparte de, que puede significar
>   ‘**además**’ (2) o ‘sin contar’ (3):
>
> (2) Eric Olhsson es diseñador gráfico y trabaja como freelance
>   **aparte** de ser músico [Graficante, acceso: 19-4-2008].
>
> (3) Aún es joven, tiene 40 años y dos meses contados, y, **aparte** de
>   unos triglicéridos rebeldes, está razonablemente sano [Fibromialgia,
>   acceso: 20-4-2008].
>
> Además, ocasionalmente, pueden coincidir la preposición a y el
>   sustantivo parte como palabras independientes en la secuencia **a
>   parte** (separado):
>
> (4) […] el conseller Huguet quiere escuchar **a parte** de la sociedad
>   digital y se va a estudiar cómo impulsar la sociedad de la información
>   [K-Government, acceso: 8-4-2008]
>
> Las apariciones de esta combinación son más bien escasas. Podemos
>   reconocerla porque admite que introduzcamos un artículo entre la
>   preposición y el nombre o incluso que añadamos un artículo y un
>   adjetivo:
>
> (5) El conseller Huguet quiere escuchar a **una** parte de la sociedad
>   digital
>
> En cambio, si hacemos la prueba con los ejemplos (1), (2) y (3),
>   veremos que no funciona. Eso nos está indicando que en esos casos hay
>   que escribir aparte junto.
>
> En resumen, antes de escribir a parte separado, desconfía y
>   compruébalo intentando introducir un artículo. Casi nunca será
>   posible.

---

Además, comenta el artículo de Fundéu [«aparte» no es lo mismo que «a parte»](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/aparte-a-parte/):

> **Aparte** se escribe **siempre en una palabra, ya sea adjetivo, adverbio o sustantivo**, mientras que la grafía *a parte*, en dos
>   palabras, solo aparece como combinación de la preposición *a* y el
>   sustantivo *parte*, como en «Esa actitud no nos llevará a parte
>   alguna».
>
> ...
>
> Tal como señala la Ortografía académica, el término [aparte](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QMWVcOxKjJTVdDUV), en
>   una sola palabra, puede funcionar como **adjetivo** con el significado
>   de **‘distinto, singular’** («La genialidad de Picasso es un caso
>   aparte en la historia del arte»), como **adverbio** con el significado
>   de **‘en otro lugar’, ‘por separado’, ‘fuera, al margen’** («Colocaron
>   las armas aparte») o como **sustantivo** equivalente a
>   ‘**conversación** entre dos o más personas **al margen** de otras
>   presentes’ («Los ministros hicieron un aparte para tratar el asunto»).
>
> ...
>
> Cuestión diferente es **la secuencia *a parte*, combinación** presente
>   en frases como «Esas leyes dejan indefensos a parte de los ciudadanos»
>   (equivalente a «… a una parte de los ciudadanos»), «Esa actitud no nos
>   llevará a parte alguna» y «La nueva pavimentación mejorará las
>   infraestructuras del municipio, puesto que la calle lo atraviesa de
>   parte a parte».

Answer (score 2):

Aunque las otras respuestas están muy bien y son muy completas, la fuentes que citan, aunque válidas, no son oficiales.
Me gustaría por ello enlazar al [artículo del DPD para la palabra "**aparte**"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=aparte), y reflejar aquí la hipersencilla regla que viene al final:

> 2. ***Aparte* se escribe siempre en una sola palabra**. No debe confundirse con la combinación ocasional de la preposición *a* y el sustantivo *parte*: *«Se trata de un camino que no conduce a parte alguna»* (País [Esp.] 6.10.77).

Comment: La cuestión es cómo identificar cuándo es "aparte" y cuando "a parte". Esa "hipersencilla regla" no lo es tanto, porque entonces yo tendría que decir "el profesor suspendió aparte de la clase" cuando debería ser "a parte de la clase".

Comment: si puedes sustituir por "a una parte" sería separado. Claro que en el ejemplo de  "a parte alguna" no funciona pero no es una construcción muy habitual y puede cambiarse por "a ninguna parte".